# Stackdriver Alerting is not available for dataflow jobs run in the region europe-west1

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm trying to create an Alerting policy for my `google-cloud-dataflow` job and noticed that its available only when the job is running in `us-central1` region. The jobs which are running in `europe-west1` are not listed in the `Resources` section in `Stackdriver`. How can I create alerting policies for my jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working for google cloud support.
It seems to be an internal issue. I've opened a public issue case for this. You can fallow the case's progress in this public issue tracker url https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73715712

Comment: The link seems broken. Can you please check?